# GDI update graphics issue

Tags: c#, gdi

i tried to search for this on google, but didnt seem to find anything related that could help me.
My problem is this, i have a **panel** in which i draw a **cube**, and i added a group box with 3 radio buttons and 4 normal buttons(these do the rotation of the **cube**)
For testing i have another button added on the **panel** but not in the group box.
The problem is this, when i push on any button it doesn't update the cube's rotation, only when i move the mouse on the test button(over it)
If i try to move the buttons outside the group box then all works well, but they don't work if they stay inside the group box.

Does anyone know how i can fix this?

Comment: I've found out how to fix this issue, I used Invalidate(); when i pressed the button in the group box.  
And i fixed it by adding drawPanel.Invalidate(); that fixed my issue, but added a new one, now the drawing flickers each time i press the button(but if i move the buttons out of the group box then they don't flicker) .

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest that instead of redrawing the panel you create a `Bitmap` for drawing your (rotated) cube and use a `PictureBox` to display it? The `PictureBox` could be inside the `Panel` together with the `GroupBox`.

Answer (score 0):

The flickering comes because the panel redraws his background first and then raises the `Paint` event. To avoid this you must to create a custom control and do the drawing in `OnPaintBackground` protected method. This seems a overkill. Or you can write to a Bitmap and put it in the `BackgroundImage` property.